# Simplification of fraction involving trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry, fractions

Let $\displaystyle \rho := \frac{\cos(\pi x)}{1 + \sin(\pi x)}$ and $\displaystyle \theta := -\frac{\pi}{2}$. How can I see, that

[image: frac]

I mean, obviously $\displaystyle \cos(\theta - \varphi) = -\sin(\varphi)$, but I somehow mess up with the simplification.

Comment: Actually, $\cos(\theta - \varphi) = -\sin(\varphi)$.

Comment: Sure, I corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $\rho=\frac{a}{1+b}\ $ i.e. $a=\cos (\pi x)$ and $b=\sin(\pi x)$. Then your LHS equals

\begin{align*}
\frac{(b+1)^2-a^2}{(b+1)^2-2a(1+b)\cos(\pi/2+\phi)+a^2}
\end{align*}

Since $a^2+b^2=1$ and $\cos(\pi/2+\phi)=-\sin(\phi)$, we have

\begin{align*}
\frac{b^2+2b+1-a^2}{2 + 2b + 2a(1+b)\sin(\phi)} &= \frac{2b^2+2b}{2 + 2b + 2a(1+b)\sin(\phi)}\\
&= \frac{b^2+b}{1 + b + a(1+b)\sin(\phi)}\\
&= \frac{b}{1 + a\sin(\phi)}\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.